# Develop a 360-Degree Video Viewer

Tags: video, interactive, 360-degrees

I'm interested in those 360-Degree video you can find on the web (like http://www.slopeviews.com/onsnow-beta/).

I am wondering how all of this is working, and how one can start to implement a view like this.

Any hint we be appreciated, thanks !

Comment: +1 I learned about something new through your question.

Comment: Im looking for more info too, have you find something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick google and found that HTML5 could allow it for almost all browsers but probably except one.

http://www.craftymind.com/2010/04/20/blowing-up-html5-video-and-mapping-it-into-3d-space/

Answer (score 2):

That is really cool. I know nothing about it but I did do a quick 'BING' and found the following which might be helpful.

http://www.pcworld.com/article/17152/how_it_works_360degree_internet_video.html

http://www.360video.com/how_it_works/